# Surfaces in isothermal coordinates and particular PDE

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes, riemannian-geometry, surfaces, curvature

From Brioschi's formula, if we have a surface in isothermal coordinates were $g_{ij}=E(u,v)*\delta_{ij}$ is the metric tensor, the gaussian curvature is:

$K=-\frac{1}{2E}[\frac{\partial}{\partial u}(\frac{E_u}{E})+\frac{\partial}{\partial v}(\frac{E_v}{E})]=-\frac{1}{2}[\frac{E(\Delta E)-(\nabla E)^2}{E^3}]$.

If $\Delta E=0$ (i.e. $(E(u,v)$ is an harmonic function), the $K$ is $\geq0$ and (being that the metric tensor is $g_{ij}=e^{\phi(u,v)}\delta_{ij}$), we have:

$K==-\frac{1}{2}e^{-\phi(u,v)}(\frac{\partial^2 \phi(u,v)}{du^2}+\frac{\partial^2 \phi(u,v)}{dv^2})=-\frac{1}{2e^\phi}(\phi_{uu}+\phi_{vv})$

were:

$E_{uu}=e^\phi \phi_u^2+e^\phi \phi_{uu}$

$E_{vv}=e^\phi \phi_v^2+e^\phi \phi_{vv}$.

Now, being $\Delta E=0$ we have:

$e^\phi(\phi_{uu}+\phi_{vv}+\phi_u^2+ \phi_v^2)=0$

namely $\Delta \phi=-(\nabla \phi)^2$.

My question is:
Has this PDE some interest, first thing in general and then from the geometrical point of view (considering the link between this PDE and the sign of curvature, which implies as seen above $K \geq 0$)?

Thank you in advance for any help!
Alex

Comment: $e^{-\phi} \Delta e^{\phi} = \Delta \phi + (\nabla\phi)^2$. Hence, for any solution $\phi$ to your equation, $\psi = e^\phi$ satisfies the Laplace equation, and vice versa (up to invertibility of the exponential function).

Comment: thank you Igor..so it's just a "coincidence" in the sense that this PDE in itself tells us nothing, let alone from the geometrical point of view and curvature .. is so?

Comment: sorry I didn't really follow the motivation for your question, so cannot say anything about it. I can only contribute the observation I made in my earlier comment.

Comment: Ah ok Igor, thanks again!! You have pointed out to me that the $\phi$ that interest me are (so to speak) in biunique correspondence with the positive harmonic functions...

Comment: In two dimensions it is well-known that for two metric $g$ and $\tilde{g}$ related conformally through $\tilde{g} = e^{\phi} g$, the scalar curvature of $\tilde{g}$ satisfies
$$ \tilde{R} = e^{-\phi} (R + \triangle \phi) $$

For metrics in isothermal parametrization, $g$ is flat, and $R = 0$. So the sign of curvature is determined by whether the log of the conformal factor is sub- or super- harmonic.

Comment: Note that the reverse problem of given $g$, solving for $\tilde{g}$ conformal such that $\tilde{g}$ has constant scalar curvature is the uniformization theorem, which can be studied from the lens of the PDE in my previous comment. (The higher dimensional case is the Yamabe problem; but the PDE becomes a bit more complicated.)